# java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, verifyerror

After i realise my App, many User send me a ANR. All ANRs are comming up frome Android 5.0.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class de.berger.marcus.nwa_app.MapsActivity$2$1 because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'de.berger.marcus.nwa_app.MapsActivity$2$1' appears in /data/app/de.berger.marcus.nwa_app-1/base.apk)
at de.berger.marcus.nwa_app.MapsActivity$2.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:181)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzo$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.v$a$a.a(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:82)
at maps.ei.bu$6.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

My Code in MapsActivity.java:181:

```
if (mapView != null) {
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {

        showGPSPreview();
        if (startGPS()==true) {googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);}
        if (startGPS()==false) {Log.d("GPS"," is OFF");}
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(52.33101, 7.91667), 8));

googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {   // THIS IS LINE 181 
@Override
    public void onMapLoaded() {

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(52.33101, 7.91667))      // Osnabrück als Zentrum
        .zoom(9)                   // Zoomstufe
        .bearing(0)                // Ausrichtung nach Norden
        .tilt(60)                   // 60 Grad Blickrichtung (Schräge)
        .build();                   // Los geht es
```

Anyone have a hind for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i have found it.
I have too many Objekts in the Map. After i delete some it works.
But its only on Android 5.0.x where the Crash comes.